# React passing props into custom carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using this.props and then the array choice to fill my attributes etc.. Is there a better way where I can pass props to shorten from this.props? Also does anyone else see anything wrong with this? It is still automatically sliding and not being "controlled".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Carousel as BSCarousel } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Carousel extends Component {
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      direction: null,
    };
  }

  handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    this.setState({
      index: selectedIndex,
      direction: e.direction,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BSCarousel activeIndex={this.state.index} direction={this.state.direction} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
        <BSCarousel.Item>
          <img alt={this.props.alt} src={this.props.image} />
          <BSCarousel.Caption>
            <h3>{this.props.heading}</h3>
            <p>{this.props.caption}</p>
          </BSCarousel.Caption>
        </BSCarousel.Item>
      </BSCarousel>
    );
  }
}

export default Carousel;
```

**EDIT**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Carousel as BSCarousel } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Carousel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { index: 0, direction: null };

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    const { alt, image, heading, caption } = this.props;

    return (
      <BSCarousel activeIndex={this.state.index} direction={this.state.direction} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
        <BSCarousel.Item>
          <img alt={alt} src={image} />
          <BSCarousel.Caption>
            <h3>{heading}</h3>
            <p>{caption}</p>
          </BSCarousel.Caption>
        </BSCarousel.Item>
      </BSCarousel>
    );
  }
}

export default Carousel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had asked if there was a way to clean up all your calls to `this.props`, so most of the answers here mention destructuring, which is a nice way to clean up your calls to `this.anything`, but then you also asked if anyone sees anything wrong with your implementation, and some answers pointed out that were using an outdated use of `getInitialState` (instead simply setup your initial component-level state in the constructor with an assignment to `this.state = {}`), **but what other answers haven't caught onto was the fact that your implementation limited your "Carousel" to only a single item, passed in via props**. **What you should do instead, is allow yourself the flexibility to pass in any number of items to your Carousel component via props.**

To me, it would be a highly-limiting Carousel component, if it only allows a single item to be passed in via props.

So here is what I would do. This implementation:

1. Uses destructuring to clean up all the repetitive dot-notation,
2. Declares Component-level state in the constructor,
3. Allows you to pass in any number of Carousel Items via props,
4. Declares a renderItems() function that renders the collection of `Carousel.Item` elements
5. Calls to a `CarouselItem` component which is responsible for creating the the actual `Carousel.Item`
6. Makes sure to bind any custom functions to `this` in the constructor (needed when your functions need to reference the `this` context),
7. Uses the spread operator to really clean up multiple calls to `this`

**components/Carousel.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CarouselItem from './CarouselItem'; // 5

class CustomCarousel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { // 2
      index: 0,
      direction: null,
    };
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this); // 6
  }

  handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    this.setState({
      index: selectedIndex,
      direction: e.direction,
    });
  }

  generateItems() { // 4
    const { items } = this.props;
    return items.map((item, index) => {
      const active = (index === item.id);
      return (<CarouselItem
        key={`CI${item.id}`}
        active={active}
        direction={this.state.direction}
        {...item} // 7
      />);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={this.state.index}
        direction={this.state.direction}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}
      >
        {this.generateItems()}
      </Carousel>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomCarousel;
```

**components/Carousel/CarouselItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Carousel } from 'react-bootstrap';

const CarouselItem = (props) => {
  const { id, active, direction, image, alt, heading, caption } = props; // 1

  return (
    <Carousel.Item
      index={id}
      active={active}
      direction={direction}
    >
      <img alt={alt} src={image} />
      <Carousel.Caption>
        <h3>{heading}</h3>
        <p>{caption}</p>
      </Carousel.Caption>
    </Carousel.Item>
  );
};

export default CarouselItem;
```

Now you have a clean Carousel Component that can accept any number of potential "Items".

You can call your Custom Carousel like this:

```
import CustomCarousel from './path/to/Carousel';

const arrayOfItemObjects = [
  {...},
  {...},
  {...}
];

<CustomCarousel 
   items={arrayOfItemObjects} // 3
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way where I can pass props to shorten from this.props?

Use destructuring

```
render() {
    const {alt, image, heading, caption} = this.props

    return (
      <BSCarousel activeIndex={this.state.index} direction={this.state.direction} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
        <BSCarousel.Item>
          <img alt={alt} src={image} />
          <BSCarousel.Caption>
            <h3>{heading}</h3>
            <p>{caption}</p>
          </BSCarousel.Caption>
        </BSCarousel.Item>
      </BSCarousel>
    );
  }
```

> Also does anyone else see anything wrong with this?

You need to bind `handleSelect` before passing it as a callback

```
class Carousel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.state = {/* initial state goes here*/}

     this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)
  }

  ... rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `es5 and es6` of writing a React Component, there is no `getInitialState` method in `es6`. Use `constructor` to initialise the `state` value.

Like this:

```
class Carousel extends Component {

   constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
          index: 0,
          direction: null,
       };
   }

....
```

Instead of accessing `this.props.key` you can use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) inside `render` method, then directly access the values by key name, like this:

```
render(){
   const {alt, image, heading, caption} = this.props;
   console.log(alt, image, heading, caption);
   return (
       <BSCarousel activeIndex={this.state.index} direction={this.state.direction} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
           <BSCarousel.Item>
               <img alt={alt} src={image} />
               <BSCarousel.Caption>
                  <h3>{heading}</h3>
                  <p>{caption}</p>
               </BSCarousel.Caption>
           </BSCarousel.Item>
       </BSCarousel>
   )
}
```

Check this snippet it will throw error, that **state is not defined**:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

   getInitialState(){
      return {a:1}
   }
   
   render(){
      return <div>Hello: {this.state.a}</div>
   }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Can you check my edit and see if I am going wrong anywhere?

Comment: try changing class name from `Carousel` to `CustomCarousel` and add props type validation in class by importing npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: Because `getInitialState` is not an `"ES6"` function, this sentence feels a little misleading: `"there is no getInitialState method in es6"` so just to clarify: You shouldn't use `getInitialState` from the React API when using ES6.

Answer (score 1):

If you tire of seeing *this.props* everywhere, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) props like this (same with this.state, or any other object you'd like to pick apart):

```
  render() {
    const { alt, heading, image, caption } = this.props;
    return (
      <BSCarousel activeIndex={this.state.index} direction={this.state.direction} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
        <BSCarousel.Item>
          <img alt={alt} src={image} />
          <BSCarousel.Caption>
            <h3>{heading}</h3>
            <p>{caption}</p>
          </BSCarousel.Caption>
        </BSCarousel.Item>
      </BSCarousel>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using ES6 classes, you have to set it up differently.

Replace your `getInitialState()` function with:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      direction: null,
    };
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
}
```